# How to use sFlow-RT with RYU (SDN Controller) for detecting flows in a Mininet Topology?

Tags: sdn, openflow, sflow

I am new to Software Defined Networking and can't really get a full grasp of it. I want to detect the flows in a Mininet Topology created in linux environment using sFlow-RT and RYU Controller.

I am using sFlow-Trend, the GUI version of the software for detecting the flows.

I approached this by creating 3 terminal windows:
First Terminal: I created the mininet topology.
Second Terminal: I ran the RYU Controller.
Third Terminal: I started the sFlow-RT on logical port 8008.

Any help in this will be appreciated, considering the limitations of any tutorials.

Commands used in linux:

For Running the s-Flow,

```
$ cd sflow-rt 
$ ./start.sh
```

For Creating Mininet,

```
$ cd sflow-rt
$ sudo mn --custom extras/sflow.py --link tc,bw=10 --topo tree,depth=2,fanout=2
```

For Starting the RYU Controller,

```
$ cd /home/ubuntu/ryu && ./bin/ryu-manager --verbose ryu/app/simple_switch_13.py
```

For Accessing the s-Flow Trend GUI, type in the browser address-bar:

```
localhost:8008
```

This link below provides the mininet commands with sFlow-RT detection of elephant flows but provides no approach to run a SDN Controller (RYU) along-with it.

[Mininet Flow Analytics](https://blog.sflow.com/2016/05/mininet-flow-analytics.html)

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Including the Ryu ofctl_rest.py module provides a REST API that allows an external application (like sFlow-RT) to implement controls in Ryu. The article, [Ryu measurement based control](https://blog.sflow.com/2018/10/ryu-measurement-based-control.html), provides an example.